# Install pip on Mac for Python3 with Python2 already installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have installed python3 on Mac and I am trying to install pip.

While installing pip with command sudo easy_install pip it installs the pip for python 2.x which by default comes with Mac.

Is there any way I can install pip for python3?

Also, is it necessary to keep the older version of python installed as well?

Comment: You have not even googled it, right?

Comment: You may already have `pip` if you installed python >=3.4. Try using the command `pip3`.

Comment: Worked for me Greg. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to specify the Python 3 version of `easy_install`. The easiest way to do this is to give its full path on the command line. It should be in the executable directory of the Python 3 installation you did (i.e. the same directory as the Python 3 interpreter itself).

You should not remove the system-installed Python 2 in an attempt to get `easy_install` to refer to Python 3, because the operating system relies on that version of Python being installed.